# kill JavaScript recursive function

Tags: jquery, javascript

I am having recursive function. it make calls every second. I want to kill that function in certain state.

```
function foo(){
      // ajax call
      //in ajax success
  success: function(response){
  setTimeout(function(){    
      foo();
   },1000);

   }  
}
```

This code makes recursive call

```
if(user == "idile"){
//here i want to kill that foo() function
}
```

how can i do this ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try to put that condition into the *success* callback function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assign the timeout to a variable like this:

```
var timer;
    function foo(){
          // ajax call
          //in ajax success
      success: function(response){
      timer = setTimeout(function(){    
          foo();
       },1000);

       }  
    }
```

and then to kill the timer:

```
if(user == "idile"){
clearTimeout(timer);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

the way you do is using global variable,

```
var isFinish= false;

function foo(){
      // ajax call
      //in ajax success
  success: function(response){
  setTimeout(function(){   
      if (!isFinish)
      { 
          foo();
      }
   },1000);
   }  
}
```

and then just change the isFinish to true

```
if(user == "idile"){
//here i want to kill that foo() function
isFinish = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you spawn your function into a different thread, do this:

```
var t;

function foo()
{
    // ajax call
    //in ajax success
    success: function(response)
    {
        t = setTimeout
        (
            function(){foo();}
            ,1000
        );
    }  
}
```

When you want to stop it, do this:

```
if(user == "idile")
{
    //here i want to kill that foo() function
    clearTimeout(t);
}
```